# Parcelable class throwing runtime exception unmarshalling unknown type

Tags: android, parcelable

I am working on an android project and trying to make use of Parcelable so I can parse the class object in a bundle to another activity.

Below is my class

```
public class GroupAndItems implements Parcelable
{


    public String group;
    public List<String> items;

    public GroupAndItems(String group, List<String> items)
    {
        this.group = group;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public GroupAndItems(Parcel in)
    {
        this.group = in.readString();
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        in.readList(this.items, null);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeList(items);
        parcel.writeString(group);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<GroupAndItems>() {

        @Override
        public GroupAndItems createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new GroupAndItems(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public GroupAndItems[] newArray(int i) {
            return new GroupAndItems[i];
        }
    };
}
```

I have `ArrayList<GroupAndItems> groupAndItemsList` which I put into the bundle and the intent as follows

```
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("groupsAndItems", groupAndItemsList);

Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), GroupedSpinnerItems.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

In the activty where I pass the parcelable class in, I retrieve it using the following:

```
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
ArrayList<GroupAndItems> groupAndItems = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("groupsAndItems");
        }
```

I am then getting the following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@5620ba2: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7143525 at offset 176
```

which is on the line

`in.readList(this.items, null);` in the constructor of my parcelable class that has `Parcel in` as the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public GroupAndItems(Parcel in)
    {

        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
        in.readList(this.items, null);
        this.group = in.readString();
    }

@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeList(items);
        parcel.writeString(group);
    }
```

You first read String in `GroupAndItems(Parcel in)` but you first write List in `writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i)` you must do that in same order all time for example if you write String then List you should read String then List

Comment: Thanks didn't see you had to follow the same order

Comment: @Boardy for the specific case of lists of `String`, you get a little bit of improvement (better performance and type safety) if you use `writeStringList()` and `createStringArrayList()` instead of the generic `writeList()` and `readList()` methods.